# form validation using isNaN()

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="basic">
        <form id="input">
            <p id="content">
              <label> Birth Year: <input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="E.g. 1020" ></label> <br></br>
              <!-- oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number.')" -->
              <label> Current Year: <input type="text" id="box2" placeholder="E.g. 1220" ></label> <br></br>
              <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="submit" onclick="calculateAge(document.getElementById('box1').value, document.getElementById('box2'.value))"/>
            </p>
           </form>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        //previous attempt at form validation and bubble error message.
        //error message for form fields
        var birth = document.getElementById('box1');
        birth.oninvalid = function(event)
        {
        event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number.');
        }
        var current = document.getElementById('box2');
        current.oninvalid = function(e)
        {
          e.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number.');
        }

        //function parameters do not have types?
        function calculateAge(birthYear, currentYear)
        {
          var a = birthYear.match("^[0-9]+$").length == 1;
          var b = currentYear.match("^[0-9]+$").length == 1;
          //var check1 = Number.isInteger(birthYear);
          //var check2 = Number.isInteger(currentYear);
          var page = document.getElementById("content");
          // fire off an error message if one of the two fields is NaN.
          if (a ==true && b==true)
          {
            //var page = document.getElementById("content");
            var content = page.innerHTML;
            var age = currentYear-birthYear;
            var stage;
            if (age <18)
            {
              stage = "Teenager";
            }
            else if (age >= 18 || age <= 35)
            {
              stage = "Adult";
            }
            else
            {
              stage = "Mature Adult";
            }
            // \n not working at all...why?
            var outputMessage = "Your stage is: " + stage + ".\n" + "Your age is: " + age + "." + '\n';
            var node = document.createTextNode(outputMessage);
            page.insertBefore(node, page.firstChild);
          }
          else
          {
            var outputMessage = "Error: please enter a number.";
            var node = document.createTextNode(outputMessage);
            page.insertBefore(node, page.firstChild);
          }
        }
        var button = document.getElementById("submit");
        button.onclick = function()
        {
          value1 = button.form.box1.value;
          value2 = button.form.box2.value;
          calculateAge(value1, value2);
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried "adopting" some of the example code for form validation and my code refused to give me a little bubble that says something along the lines of "wrong input!" like the example code on the documentation had, so i decided to go with a simpler approach.

My goal is to check if the inputs from the form fields are number (no letters/symbols), so im doing an if check to do what i want the form result to do (output the stage/age of the person given their info), else I just want it to fire off a generic error message.

However, the error message does not get fired off even if the "age" output is "NaN". for example filling in box1 with a letter and box 2 with a number, you get stage: (blank) age: NaN. What am I missing?

Edit: implemented suggested change, and changed if check condition.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have to validate the input first by checking if it is a number, since you cant calculate strings with numbers obviously.

Take a look at [Number.isInteger(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger), this is what you need. ;)

Here an overview of its outputs:

```
Number.isInteger(0);         // true
Number.isInteger(1);         // true
Number.isInteger(-100000);   // true

Number.isInteger(0.1);       // false
Number.isInteger(Math.PI);   // false

Number.isInteger(Infinity);  // false
Number.isInteger(-Infinity); // false
Number.isInteger("10");      // false
Number.isInteger(true);      // false
Number.isInteger(false);     // false
Number.isInteger([1]);       // false
```

**Edit: [Additions]**
Also your code is wrong.

```
// fire off an error message if one of the two fields is NaN.
if (check1 ==true || check2==true)
```

[isNaN(testValue)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) returns true if testValue is not a number. So what you do in your code is, you check if check1 OR check2 is not a number and if yes, you continue. I dont think thats what you wanted? Because in the else is your error message, and this else will only be called when both are false (means both of them must be not NaN's and this means you write the error exactly then when all is right)

Correct you should ask, when using IsNaN:

```
if(check1 == false && check2 == false) {
  // Everything okay - No error
} else {
  // One of them, or both, is not a number - Print error
}
```

Comment: The user input is going to be a string, so perhaps using `inputValue.match("^[0-9]+$").length == 1` would be better ;)

Comment: @KoalaGangsta thank you, thats what i was looking for.

Comment: @KoalaGangsta hmm, now it treats everything as not an integer and only throws the error.

Comment: Always happy to help :) I edited the post, since there is a small mistake in your code which could lead to unwanted behavoir if you dont see it early enough before it gets lost somewhere in the code ^^

Comment: This might be the problem, try to fix the if-end and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: @KoalaGangsta yep, i spotted that as i was implementing your first suggestion, now that i changed the code to false on both, it goes back to what it was before with it putting NaN as the age.

Comment: Sorry ShadowBlade is right, I didnt look into your full code and didnt notice that you get the value by the text input which obviously gives you a string back. Sorry for the inconvinience!

Comment: @AndrewMorton So, I would use birthYear.match("^[0-9]+$").length == 1; ? Does that return an integer or a boolean? I dont know how to use that expression.

Comment: @ShadowBlade The expression is testing for `x == y`, the result of which is a boolean.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So, I will edit the code with your suggestion implemented, but when putting a letter into the field it simply throws a null error into the console rather than printing the error into the page as desired. Also, any age >35 will be printed correctly at the age section but it seems to ignore the else statement and never assigns the stage to "Mature Adult", do you know what i did wrong?

Comment: @ShadowBlade In the line `var age = currentYear-birthYear;` you need to convert both of  the variables (because they are strings) to numbers before you can do maths on them. E.g. `var age = pareseInt(currentYear) - parseInt(birthYear);`.

Comment: Because, again, youre checking for if the age is bigger/same as 18 OR smaller/same as 35 instead of checking with AND. ;)